# Rhandsontable/shiny/ undo

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I have a shiny app with an integrated rhandsontable, I have a "undo" button which undoes all changes at once (so for example if I changed 5 values, then click "undo" all 5 values are reverted simultaneously)

Is there any possibility to implement a second version of the undo button so that the changes are reverted one by one, so undo would only revert the single most recent change, i.e. after changing 3 values, I would have to click the undo button 3 times to revert all changes?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

change_hook <- "function(el,x) {
var hot = this.hot;  
var cellChanges = [];

var changefn = function(changes,source) { 
if (source === 'edit' || source === 'undo' || source === 'autofill' || source === 'paste') {
row = changes[0][0];
col = changes[0][1];
oldval = changes[0][2];
newval = changes[0][3];

if (oldval !== newval) {
  var cell = hot.getCell(row, col);
  cell.style.background = 'cyan';
  cellChanges.push({'rowid':row, 'colid':col});
}
}
}

var renderfn = function(isForced) {

for(i = 0; i < cellChanges.length; i++)
{

var rowIndex = cellChanges[i]['rowid'];
var columnIndex = cellChanges[i]['colid'];

var cell = hot.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
cell.style.background = 'cyan';

}


}

var loadfn = function(initialLoad) {

for(i = 0; i < cellChanges.length; i++)
    {
      var rowIndex = cellChanges[i]['rowid'];
      var columnIndex = cellChanges[i]['colid'];

      var cell = hot.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);

      cell.style.background = 'white';

    }
cellChanges = []

}


hot.addHook('afterChange', changefn);
hot.addHook('afterRender', renderfn);
hot.addHook('afterLoadData', loadfn);


}  "


ui <- div(actionButton(inputId = "undo_button",label = "undo")
          ,rHandsontableOutput(outputId="mtcars"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  undo <- reactiveVal(0)
  output$mtcars <- renderRHandsontable({
    r = undo()
    rht = rhandsontable(mtcars,reset=r,stretchH="all",height=300)
    undo(0)
    htmlwidgets::onRender(rht,change_hook)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$undo_button,
               {
                 undo(1)
               })
}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need such a button as the functionality is already implemented by `{rhandsontable}` out of the box:

- `Ctrl + z`: Undo
- `Ctrl + y`: Redo

What I suggest, however, is a rethinking of what to render and when to re-render.

In this example, I show how you can achieve both of the functionalities you're after:

- Undo (and redo) changes, one by one. Of course, using `Ctrl + z` & `Ctrl + y`, respectively.
- An undo button which reverts all changes made at once.

[image: An example showing the functionalities]

```r
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Handsontable"),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot", height = 500),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "undo_all",
    label = "Undo all changes",
    icon = icon(
      name = "arrow-rotate-left",
      class = "fa-sharp fa-light"
    ),
    style = "margin-top: 20px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # reactive containing the original dataset:
  r_original <- reactive({ iris })
  
  # reactive value to track changes to the dataset:
  rv_current <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)
  
  # in case the original dataset is changed, update 'rv_current':
  observeEvent(r_original(), {
    rv_current(r_original())
  })
  
  # in case the rhandsontable is edited, update 'rv_current':
  observeEvent(input$hot, {
    current <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    rv_current(current)
  })
  
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(
      data = r_original(), # NOTE: Render 'r_original()', NOT 'rv_current()'
      readOnly = FALSE,
      useTypes = TRUE,
      stretchH = "all"
    )
  }) |> 
    bindEvent(r_original(), input$undo_all)
  # The bindEvent tells shiny to only re-render the table if 'r_original()'
  # changes or when 'undo_all' button is clicked.
  
  # You can now use 'rv_current()' for any calculations on the newest state of
  # the table
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```